# Do indexes overlap whenever possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

suppose I have a table with 2 columns I already know I will never use together into the same query. So, something like:

```
BLACK | WHITE | C1 | C2 | C3 | B1 | B2 | B3 | ...
```

I also know that in about 80% of my queries I will ask C1 C2 and C3 along with one of either BLACK or WHITE.
If I define an index like:

```
C1,C2,C3, BLACK
```

When I go defining the index

```
C1,C2,C3, WHITE
```

Will I reuse the first part, including C1,C2,C3? Or a brand new index (and its related disk space) will be created?

Also, suppose that C1 is the column with the highest number of dinstinct values (in my DB it's a date time column), is it right to put it into the first place? Or is it better to put C3, supposing that C3 is the one with less dinstinct values?

Answer (score 0):

> Will I reuse the first part, including C1,C2,C3? Or a brand new index (and its related disk space) will be created?

There will be two distinct indexes occupying twice as many data pages (assuming `black` and `white` have similar sizes)

> Also, suppose that C1 is the column with the highest number of dinstinct values (in my DB it's a date time column), is it right to put it into the first place? Or is it better to put C3, supposing that C3 is the one with less dinstinct values?

This depends on your queries.

The index can be used both for filtering and ordering.

If you create an index on `C1, C2, C3`, you can use if for filtering and/or ordering on any of `(C1)`, `(C1, C2)`, and `(C1, C2, C3)`.

Comment: And there isn't any workaround to not use twice the memory? Regarding the other question I am troubled more about query performance